# Wordpress Search widget

Tags: wordpress

Hello I have a problem in my widget. There is a search engine in the widget. I want to add dropdown input option in the widget but I get an error(500). My code is like that:

```
    <div class="dropdown form-control search_location_mobile_wrapp search_location_list_wrapp">
        <div data-toggle="dropdown" id="search_location_list" class="filter_menu_trigger" 
            data-value="<?php  
                if(isset($_GET['search_location'])){
                    echo esc_attr($_GET['search_location']);
                }else{
                    echo 'all';
                }
            ?>"> 
           <?php  
            if( isset($_GET['search_location'])){
               echo esc_html__($_GET['search_location'],'wpestate');
            }else{
          esc_html_e('Where do you want to go ?','wpestate');
            }?>     
            <span class="caret caret_filter"></span>
        </div>           
        <input type="hidden" name="search_location" id="search_location_list" 
            value="<?php  
            if(isset($_GET['search_location'])){
                echo esc_attr($_GET['search_location']);
            }?>">
     <ul  class="dropdown-menu filter_menu"  id="guest_no_main_list" role="menu" aria-labelledby="search_location">
            <?php print wpestate_get_city_select_list($args);?>
        </ul>        
    </div>
```

What is a problem ?

Comment: I add my code but it is not visible sorry for that

Comment: Don't you think we need more details?